# What to do about popular answers that aren't actually correct?

Tags: discussion

So, a question about [uncredited actors in films](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/15756/why-are-some-actors-uncredited-in-certain-films) recently got bumped up after a year.  It has one top answer with many (11 as of writing) upvotes. Even when it was originally answered, there were many comments asking about the answer (with very few good responses).  After reading through it, the answer is pretty unhelpful (in my opinion) and the idea that someone would take no credit because they aren't getting a big paycheck is not only nonsensical, it's actually opposite to reality. Sometimes talent will be offered **better** billing so they will accept a lower pay.

So, I've answered the question with much more info but with only one downvote in my arsenal, I'm not sure what to do. Even after adding my answer, the old answer actually got another upvote...

I'm using this as a specific example but I've seen [similar questions](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10222/can-an-incorrect-accepted-answer-be-deleted?cb=1) on metas on other stacks.

Comment: While this is a valid concern and this situation happens now and then, there's not really much you can do about it other than downvote and comment on the supposedly bad answer and trust in future visitors to not get distracted by the existing upvotes but actually vote responsibly and thus for the votes to naturally adjust tehmselves to the helpfulness of the answers (if they will is another question, but at least they *should*, that's a far as you can get).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its interesting the way that the Arqade moderators respond to the question you give as an example on another site, because it seems to go against the StackExchange model.

On all SE sites, if someone flags an answer and a reviewer declines the flag, one of the specific pre-worded reasons that the reviewer can choose in response to the flag is:

> flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or **an altogether wrong answer**

This indicates to me, that its not for me or other reviewers to judge what is an wrong answer. SE gives us the ability to comment, vote, edit and write our own answers - and these are the only things we can do if we see something we believe to be incorrect or unhelpful.

There are some questions on meta.SE which back up this position, for example:

- [Moderator declined an altogether wrong answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173249/moderator-declined-an-altogether-wrong-answer)
- [Why was my flag declined for a wrong answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221732/why-was-my-flag-declined-for-a-wrong-answer)
- [Question with wrong answer upvoted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8574/question-with-wrong-answer-upvoted)

Comment: So, if comments are the best solution, with my example, is there a way to change the order of comments so that newer comments are the ones that appear rather than old comments? There are so many comments on the first answer that notes I've added aren't visible and the answer is still getting more upvotes... It's up to 12 now.

Comment: @Catija - no, there is no way to change the order of comments - except by people voting them up.   I'll have a quick look at the comments on that post and see if any can be removed if they are no longer relevant, which might bump yours into visibility.  You can always write your own answer too.

Comment: I did write my own answer. And, honestly, I don't have the rep to flag anything.  It would be nice if up and down votes were shown separately rather than the running total.

Comment: Oh, I guess I can flag stuff... but I completely respect the purpose of flags and I doubt I'll use it unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: @Catija - well you will get the reputation with time, I have no doubt.  Welcome to the site !

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, the welcome and for upvoting my comments so they show up (I'm assuming that was you).